How to convert daily ERA5 data to Monthly mean data in GEE
I want to convert daily max temperature data to monthly average from ERA5 daily data
// Combine shapefiles into a list
var shapefiles = [
  table, table2
];
var variables = [
  'temperature_2m_max',
  'dewpoint_temperature_2m_max'
];

// Define the time range for the data extraction
var startDate = '1990-01-01';  // Adjust to your desired start date
var endDate = '2023-12-31';    // Adjust to your desired end date

// Load the ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR')
                .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// Function to process each variable for a given shapefile
function processVariableForShapefile(shapefile, variableName) {
  // Select and clip the variable to the shapefile region
  var variableCollection = dataset.select(variableName).map(function(image) {
    return image.clip(shapefile);
  });

  // Export daily data as a CSV
  var dailyData = variableCollection.map(function(image) {
    var date = image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd');
    image=ee.Image(image).subtract(273.15);
    var stats = image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: shapefile.geometry(),
      scale: 1000
    });
    return ee.Feature(null, stats).set('Year-Month', date);
  });


   Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: dailyData,
    folder: 'UPalldistricts',
    description: variableName + shapefile.getInfo().id,
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });
}

// Loop over each shapefile and variable
shapefiles.forEach(function(shapefile) {
  variables.forEach(function(variable) {
    processVariableForShapefile(shapefile, variable);
  });
});```


This is the code I have used to extract daily max temperature data ,I want to average it on monthly basis?


You can iterate over the months and create a monthly mean for each.
var startDate = ee.Date('2019-09-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2024-05-30')

var months = endDate.difference(startDate, 'months')
var monthlyMean = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, months.subtract(1))
    .map(function (monthOffset) {
      var date = startDate.advance(monthOffset, 'months')
      return ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR')
        .select('temperature_2m_max')
        .filterDate(date.getRange('month'))
        .mean() // Monthly mean
        .subtract(273.15)
        .set('system:time_start', date.millis())
    })
)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8cdcc9f2ed694c757af0803e3ea5213c
This you can convert to a feature collection for exporting, just like you did above.

Thank you .This code is not work when using for many shapefiles at once. Please help

In what way is it failing?

it is showing Error: DateRange: Cannot interpret  as a Date. (Error code: 3)

Then perhaps you're doing something invalid with the output of date.getRange('month')?

I am taking daily aggregate era5 data for getting daily max temperature I want to get the month mean of these daily max values.

Is there any other way to do this?
